# PyQt4 GUI to exe using py2exe - Adding python27.dll causes crash

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, pyqt4, py2exe

I have created a GUI using PyQt4 (PyQt4.QtGui and PyQt4.QtCore), this GUI includes graphing using matplotlib, importing a couple of modules I wrote myself, the GUI also has an icon.
I am using Python2.7.

My modules are in the same directory as `GUI.py`, as is the `icon.jpg`.

My setup.py code:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe, sys, os

import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.use('Qt4Agg') #I use this is GUI.py

sys.argv.append('py2exe')

includes = ['sip', 'PyQt4', 'PyQt4.QtGui', 'PyQt4.QtCore', 'matplotlib.backends']

excludes = ['_gtkagg', '_tkagg', 'bsddb', 'curses', 'pywin.debugger',
            'pywin.debugger.dbgcon', 'pywin.dialogs', 'tcl',
            'Tkconstants', 'pydoc', 'doctest', 'test', 'wx']

packages = ['matplotlib'] #should my custom modules go in here?

dll_excludes = ["MSVCP90.dll", "MSWSOCK.dll", "mswsock.dll", "powrprof.dll",
            'libgdk-win32-2.0-0.dll', 'libgobject-2.0-0.dll', 'tcl84.dll',
            "libgdk_pixbuf-2.0-0.dll"]

data_files = mpl.get_py2exe_datafiles()


setup(name = "main",
      windows = [{"script":"GUI.py", "icon_resources": [(1, "icon.jpg")]}],
      options = {'py2exe': {
          'compressed': True,
          'includes': includes,
          'excludes': excludes,
          'packages': packages,
          'dll_excludes': dll_excludes,
          'bundle_files': 1}},
      zipfile = None,
      data_files = data_files
)
```

The problem is when I run `python setup.py` on the cmd it gets to `Adding python27.dll as resource` and then i get an error saying python.exe has stopped working. Why is this, and how do I fix it?

Also, if there are other things that I should include, or conversely exclude please inform me what they are.

Comment: setup certainly shouldn't crash and that sounds like some sort of problem with your installation.  I don't know how to debug that.  Are you using a standard distribution or did you build it all from Python and the other packages yourself?

Comment: Another thing - I have switched from py2exe to cx_freeze which seems to be a bit more robust and easier to use.  Which doesn't answer you question but might be a way forward.

Comment: @strubbly i was using std dist, and after reinstalling python the python27.dll was there but i hit other problems so i changed to using pyinstaller which works perfectly with one cmd command.